# Cleanup the cache on Visual Editor

Tags: eclipse, swing, visual-editor

VE is a dead project, I know, but I still prefer it to any other option currently available (including handcoding and Google-sponsored WindowBuilder).

Its only drawback for me is that its parser sometimes stops working for no good reason - if you pasted your code into a new class, VE would correctly recognise it.

I couldn't find any temporary files that looked like VE's cache so I could delete them and force actual, complete reparsing.

So does anyone know how to refresh it when VE works funny?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version are you using?

> The Visual Editor caches information about a class and under some builds prior to VE 1.1 there are some issues with the cache going stale and not being automatically refreshed.  If this occurs you can manually recycle the cache by selecting Project > Clean and also manually removing the directory **org.eclipse.ve.beaninfo/cache** from the workbench directory.

Comment: I use the latest (actually the *last*) version... the beaninfo directory doesn't seem to exist. Anyway is the Clean command available Helios EE? Can't find it either

Comment: Can't reproduce my issue at the moment but if I don't get other answer the bounty will be all yours ;)